# Is using std::tuple to implement operator<, = etc. efficient and correct?

Tags: c++

I find that I am recently often using std::tuple to implement ordering, equality operators, like in below example. Is this a correct and efficient approach? Its especially usefull when multiple variables should be compared in such operators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

struct CustomerHash;
class Customer {
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    Customer(const std::string& name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {
    }
    
    bool operator<(const Customer& rop) const {
        return std::tuple<std::string, int>(name, age) < std::tuple<std::string, int>(rop.name, rop.age);
    }
    bool operator==(const Customer& rop) const {
        return std::tuple<std::string, int>(name, age) == std::tuple<std::string, int>(rop.name, rop.age);
    }
    
    friend struct CustomerHash;
};

struct CustomerHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Customer& c) const {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(c.name) ^ c.age;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::unordered_set<Customer, CustomerHash> cmap;
    cmap.insert({"Mike", 40});
    cmap.insert({"Andy", 42});
    cmap.insert({"Jon", 40});
    std::cout << cmap.contains({"Andy", 42});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You potentially pessimize by copying. `std::tie` is both shorter, and produces a tuple of references. If it gets inlined, you may end up with code that is equivalent to a hand-written implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct, but it's not efficient, because the constructor of `std::tuple` will copy all the values. This also means you can't use it to compare non-copyable types.

Instead you could use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), which needs a bit less code and doesn't copy the values, but creates a tuple of references.

Your `operator<` would then become:

```
bool operator<(const Customer& rop) const {
        return std::tie(name, age) < std::tie(rop.name, rop.age);
}
```

Comment: Information on copying is definitively important for me, and std::tie is perfect solution

Answer (score 4):

It definitely works. It might simply be a tiny bit inefficient as the std::tuple constructor will copy the parameters. But if that doesn't show in your performance profile, you might just not care about performance there.

I'd be more wary of:

```
std::hash<std::string>()(c.name) ^ c.age
```

Here, the age will affect only the last 9 bits of the hash, and as such might not distribute so well. Multiply `c.age` by some large prime. But hey, I'm probably nitpicking.

Comment: I would suggest using `std::reference_wrapper` to avoid the overhead of copying, and improving the likelyhood of the compiler completely optimizing away the tuple itself.

Comment: I was thinking also to use: std::hash<std::string>()(c.name) ^ std::hash<int>()(c.age)

Answer (score 0):

**Using C++20 you may now simply implement the <=> operator for your struct.** Which will allow the struct to be lexicographically compared.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Comparison_operators

"The inequality operator is automatically generated by the compiler if operator== is defined. Likewise, the four relational operators are automatically generated by the compiler if the three-way comparison operator operator<=> is defined. operator== and operator!=, in turn, are generated by the compiler if operator<=> is defined as defaulted:"

```
struct Record
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int floor;
    double weight;
    
    auto operator<=>(const Record&) const = default;
};
// records can now be compared with ==, !=, <, <=, >, and >=
std::set<Record> records; // Will now function as expected when inserting elements.
```

We can also customize the comparison operator to for example only depend on the first 2 elements for comparison.

```
constexpr std::strong_ordering operator<=>(Record lhs, Record rhs)
{
    if (lhs.name < rhs.name or (lhs.name == rhs.name and lhs.floor < rhs.floor))
        return std::strong_ordering::less;
    if (lhs.name > rhs.name or (lhs.name == rhs.name and lhs.floor > rhs.floor))
        return std::strong_ordering::greater;
    return std::strong_ordering::equivalent;
}
```

**The other option would be to implement your own comparison operator.** We can examine the implementation of the tuple < comparison operator and mimic it.
Source:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp

"3-6) Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically by operator<, that is, compares the first elements, if they are equivalent, compares the second elements, if those are equivalent, compares the third elements, and so on.
3) For empty tuples, returns false. For non-empty tuples, the effect is equivalent to"

```
if (std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs)) return true;
if (std::get<0>(rhs) < std::get<0>(lhs)) return false;
if (std::get<1>(lhs) < std::get<1>(rhs)) return true;
if (std::get<1>(rhs) < std::get<1>(lhs)) return false;
...
return std::get<N - 1>(lhs) < std::get<N - 1>(rhs);
```

Here is an example of such an implementation:

Source: https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/simplifying-lexicographical-comparisons-with-c--

```
friend bool operator<(const Time& lhs, const Time& rhs) {

//
// First compare by hours
//
if (lhs.m_hours < rhs.m_hours) {
  return true;
}
if (lhs.m_hours > rhs.m_hours) {
  return false;
}

//
// Same hours, compare by minutes
//
if (lhs.m_minutes < rhs.m_minutes) {
  return true;
}
if (lhs.m_minutes > rhs.m_minutes) {
  return false;
}

//
// Same hours and minutes, compare by seconds
// (left as an exercise for the reader...)
//

}
```

**Last option is to use std::tie with a temporary tuple of references.** You would still be instantiating "something" in this case. See Lukas-T's answer.